# JXA 'Can't convert types'

Tags: javascript-automation, apple-numbers

JavaScript for Apple Numbers - I'm trying to use the row.address of a selected range to step through a for{} loop, but the values returned aren't compatible integers (if that makes sense). A spreadsheet is open, and several rows are selected when the script runs.

```
var firstRow = cells[0].row.address;
var lastRow = cells[cells.length-1].row.address;
// these values seem valid, and can be inserted into the spreadsheet
cells[0].value = firstRow;
cells[1].value = lastRow;

for (i=firstRow; i<lastRow; i++) {
// this generates an error that terminates the script:
//     The action "Run JavaScript" encountered
//     an error: "Error: Error: Can't convert types."
    cells[2].value = i; // this line never runs
}
```

If I use math on firstRow or lastRow, I get the same error (e.g., `var j = lastRow+1`), so it's like the 'integer' value isn't really an integer value. How do I reference these values as integers, or at least so as to not get the error?

Thanks.

Comment: after more investigation, it turns out the documentation from Apple does not seem to be entirely correct. It indicates that the `cells[x].row.address` , et.al., are integers, but `typeof()` returns `function`. I have no idea how to change a `function` type to an `integer`. Not at all conducive to learning JXA. Moved the project to Applescript, and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to run the `get`ter on address. It's all in the poor documentation: `firstRow = cells[0].row.address();` should do the trick.

`address` is an "ObjectSpecifier", and `address()` is syntactic sugar to get the value of whatever this ObjectSpecifier points to.
You could try to get the properties of objects in JXA with `app.properties(object)`,  but that doesn't always work.